# What is $\int \sqrt{\cos(2Q)} / {\sin(Q)} \,\mathrm{d}Q$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> What is
>   $$
>   \int \frac{\sqrt{\cos(2Q)}}{\sin(Q)} \,\mathrm{d}Q?
> $$

I have tried all the method which is possible but could not able to find the solution. Can anyone please tell me the solution of this problem.

Comment: Is this what you meant:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\cos 2q}}{\sin q} \, \mathrm{d}q$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B2*Cot%5Bx%5D%5D,x%5D) looks rather unpleasant

Comment: Tip: expand the double-angle cosine using the double angle formula.

Comment: I done that still can't solve

Comment: Sorry the correction question is what tolaso sugested

Answer (score 1):

First notice that 
\begin{equation}
\cos\left(2x\right)=\cos^2\left(x\right)-\sin^2\left(x\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 \sin\left(x\right)=\dfrac{\tan\left(x\right)}{\sec\left(x\right)}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
 {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos\left(2x\right)}}{\sin\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
 ={\displaystyle\int}
 \sec^2(x) \cdot{{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\tan^2\left(x\right)}}{\tan\left(x\right)\left(\tan^2\left(x\right)+1\right)}}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
Change of variable as 
\begin{equation}
 u = \tan (x)
\end{equation}
we get
\begin{equation}
  {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos\left(2x\right)}}{\sin\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-u^2}}{u\left(u^2+1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u 
\end{equation}
Another change of variable as 
\begin{equation}
 v = \sqrt{1 - u^2}
\end{equation}
gives us 
\begin{equation}
  {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos\left(2x\right)}}{\sin\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
=-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{v^2}{\left(v^2-2\right)\left(v^2-1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v
\end{equation}
Now let's factor the denominator as 
\begin{equation}
  {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos\left(2x\right)}}{\sin\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{v^2}{\left(v-1\right)\left(v+1\right)\left(v^2-2\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v
\end{equation}
Then perform partial fraction decomposition
\begin{equation}
{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos\left(2x\right)}}{\sin\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
 ={\displaystyle\int}\left(\dfrac{2}{v^2-2}+\dfrac{1}{2\left(v+1\right)}-\dfrac{1}{2\left(v-1\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}v
 =
 2A + \frac{1}{2}B - \frac{1}{2} C
\end{equation}
Let's do $A$, 
\begin{equation}
 A = {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{v^2-2}\,\mathrm{d}v
 =
 ={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(v-\sqrt{2}\right)\left(v+\sqrt{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v
 ={\displaystyle\int}\left(\dfrac{1}{2^\frac{3}{2}\left(v-\sqrt{2}\right)}-\dfrac{1}{2^\frac{3}{2}\left(v+\sqrt{2}\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}v
\end{equation}
which s
\begin{equation}
 A
 =
 =\dfrac{\ln\left(v-\sqrt{2}\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}}-\dfrac{\ln\left(v+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}}
\end{equation}
Now, similarly 
\begin{equation}
 B =\ln\left(v+1\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 C =\ln\left(v-1\right)
\end{equation}
Plugging all $A,B,C$ back we get 
\begin{equation}
{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos\left(2x\right)}}{\sin\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
 =-\dfrac{\ln\left(v+\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{\ln\left(v-\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{\ln\left(v+1\right)}{2}-\dfrac{\ln\left(v-1\right)}{2}
\end{equation}
Undoing the change of variable $v = \sqrt{1 - u^2}$, we get
\begin{equation}
 {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{\cos\left(2x\right)}}{\sin\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{1-u^2}+\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{1-u^2}-\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{1-u^2}+1\right)}{2}+\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{1-u^2}-1\right)}{2}
\end{equation}
Undoing the other change of variable $u = \tan (x)$, we get
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{1-\tan^2\left(x\right)}+\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{1-\tan^2\left(x\right)}-\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{1-\tan^2\left(x\right)}+1\right)}{2}+\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{1-\tan^2\left(x\right)}-1\right)}{2}
\end{equation}
Now, depending where you're integrating, you've got to have absolute values in the arguments of the logarithms.

Comment: what is the mistake @RajeshGupta?